# NestJs app not connecting to angular app in production

Tags: nestjs, production

Can someone help me how to deploy my nestjs app on local network/server? I want to start my nestjs app on my computer for people who can access from their computer in the same local network by using angular app that has been successfully deployed on Microsoft IIS. Right now, I used npm start command to start my nestjs app and it is accessible through localhost:3000 on my computer. I do not know if I have to deploy it on IIS as well. If yes, can anyone help me how to deploy nestjs app on IIS from the beginning to end?

Comment: "local network/server?" very different to production. I'm struggling to understand your question, would I be correct in thinking that you can connect to your nestjs app when it's deployed to IIS, however, when it's on your computer (locally) no other computers on your network can access it? If that's the case, use --bind=0.0.0.0 with `yarn start` or what ever you use to start the nestjs application. If not, please provide some more information with examples or whats working and whats not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am actually hosting my app on pm2 on one of our servers. But, it is not working when no user is logged in to the server. I would love to host my nestjs app on IIS, but I do not know how and I cannot find any resources on the internet. Do you happen to know how to host nestjs app on IIS?